# Tried calling FirebaseX.subscribe, but the FirebaseX plugin is not installed

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently ran in to this problem out of no where. Every thing was working perfectly fine before, but recently I am not able to subscribe to a topic. I cant see the topics name on the cloud messaging portal.

```
Tried calling FirebaseX.subscribe, but the FirebaseX plugin is not installed

common.js:279 Install the FirebaseX plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add 
cordova-plugin-firebasex'
```

The weird part is that I already have the plugin installed.
I ran the following commands.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-x
```

Here is a part of my cordova plugin list

```
    cordova-plugin-firebasex 9.0.2-cli "Google Firebase Plugin"
    cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.7.0-20200330-2338 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
    cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
    cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
    cordova-plugin-market 1.2.0 "Market"
    cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.3.2 "NativeStorage"
    cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
    cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
    cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
    cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
    cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.7 "SocialSharing"
    cordova-promise-polyfill 0.0.2 "cordova-promise-polyfill"
```

Any one familiar with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates the plugin is not available at runtime; this could be because the plugin failed to install into your project.

Remove and re-add the mobile platform, e.g.

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios --nosave && ionic cordova platform add ios --nosave --verbose
```

Then look for errors in the console output.

(If testing Android then substitute `android` for `ios` above).

Answer (score 0):

did you get the error message "Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 8.1.1, failed version requirement: >=9" while installing the plugin.

Supported Cordova Versions

```
cordova: >= 9
cordova-android: >= 8
cordova-ios: >= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work when using live reload, i.e. when I use `ionic cordova run android`, but it does work when I use `ionic cordova build android` and get the apk file transferred on the phone. The apk file should be in /platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug.

You can then use adb install to transfer the file to your phone.